# How to define a category path of a product while importing csv sheet?

Tags: magento2, category

I am trying to add products to my website and the category path I am defining is in this format (Default Category,Default Category/Subjects,Default Category/Subjects/Business Management)

[image: Look an image below]

instead of adding the product into an existing category which I created manually it created a new category for the imported product like, in this case, it is Business management.

[image: see below writing | research methods category]

The category which I created manually (Business Management) is showing 0 products added in it.

[image: category created manually is under Bio-Science | Agriculture]

I tried some alternate methods to overcome this problem by using category id instead of using category name.

[image: see below I used category id]

but I got these results.

[image: Result]

Please suggest me some methods to solve this problem.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can assign categories to products in the format

```
Default Category, Default Category/Parent Category/Sub Category/
```

Use category name instead of category ids.

Try with this and don't forget to clear the cache and reindex.

Comment: I tried the path which you suggested Default Category, Default Category/Parent Category/Sub Category/ and it didn't work.